# If matrix $A$ is invertible, then there is a permutation of its rows leaving no-zeros on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

I need to prove this statement: "*If $A$ invertible, then exist a permutation of its rows leaving no-zeros on the diagonal*" and I tried using the definitos of invertible matrices and $LU$ factorization, but without results.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 7):

Consider the full expansion of the determinant. If it is nonzero, then at least one of its terms must be.

Comment: What about permutations? I cannot get it sorry...

Comment: @Jody: Each term in the full expansion is $\pm a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}$ for some permutation $\sigma$. If the term is nonzero, then all its factors are nonzero too, and doing this permuation (or its inverse; I'm too lazy to figure out which) of the rows of the matrix will move exactly these elements to the diagonal.